# Titled pane css settings

Tags: css, javafx-2

I wonder how to apply CSS settings to a `TitledPane`, but can't find any example

I would like to apply custom settings for `TitledPane` toolbar and background, but this does not work

```
.titled-pane
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(aliceblue, lightslategray);
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Default css of titled pane...change it according your need.

```
.titled-pane 
{
-fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TitledPaneSkin";    
-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
}
.titled-pane:focused 
{
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
.titled-pane > .title 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.833333em 0.25em 0.833333em; /* 2 10 3 10 */
}

.titled-pane:focused > .title 
{
-fx-color: -fx-focus-color;
}

.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button 
{
-fx-background-color: null;
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-padding: 0.0em 0.25em 0.0em 0.0em; /* 0 3 0 0 */
}

.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
-fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
-fx-padding: 0.25em 0.3125em 0.25em 0.3125em; /* 3 3.75 3 3.75 */
-fx-shape: "M 0 0 h 7 l -3.5 4 z";
}

.titled-pane:collapsed > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-rotate: -90;
}

.titled-pane > *.content 
{
-fx-background-color:
-fx-box-border,
linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color,-02%), derive(-fx-color,65%) 12%,      derive(-fx-color,23%) 88%, derive(-fx-color,50%) 99%, -fx-box-border);
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 1;
-fx-padding: 0.167em;
 }

.titled-pane:focused > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: @Anshul...thank you very much that's just what I was searching for

Comment: What's its stylesheet name and where is it called?

Comment: @KeepMove: Just have a look at modena.css, the default theme in JavaFX: https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470

Comment: How to use this css class in fxml file

Answer (score 5):

Only the following properties are available for titled pane( which include all labeled properties and font properties)

extra properties

```css
-fx-animated
-fx-collapsible
```

labeled properties

```css
-fx-alignment
-fx-text-alignment
-fx-text-overrun
-fx-wrap-text
-fx-font
-fx-underline
-fx-graphic
-fx-content-display          
-fx-graphic-text-gap         
-fx-label-padding        
-fx-text-fill        
-fx-ellipsis-strin
```

font properties

```css
-fx-font
-fx-font-family
-fx-font-size
-fx-font-style
-fx-font-weight
```

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation for CSS styling Titled Panes [can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane) (see @siddharth gupta's answer regarding possible properties).

You may consider to style only a certain sub-component, e.g., `.titled-pane > .title > .text`. Titled panes have the following layout:

- titled-pane - `TitledPane`

  - title — `HBox`

    - text — `Label`
    - arrow-button — `StackPane`

      - arrow — `StackPane`
  - content — `StackPane`

Here is the default formatting for the `TitledPane`'s "header":

```
.titled-pane > .title 
{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.833333em 0.25em 0.833333em; /* 2 10 3 10 */
}
```