# Java accordion flat UI design

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I want to make a flat UI with java fx.I am using NetBeans and scene builder.Does anyone know how to make the accordion looks like a flat design and to change its colour?
I tried to change the colour using -fx-background-color. But it didn't work.

Comment: Try styling TitledPane as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451386/titled-pane-css-settings)