# JavaFX - Can't remove arrow glow from TitledPane

Tags: css, javafx

I've checked a few solutions like [How to set/remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065096/how-to-set-remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane), [Titled pane css settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451386/titled-pane-css-settings) and [Remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane with CSS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607725/remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane-with-css-not-working). Also checked the [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) (*line **1829***), but when I click on the `TitledPane` (i.e. when it's focused), the arrow always keeps glowing like in the image below (might be a bit hard to see).

**Default** [image: default] **Focused**[image: focused]

This is my `CSS`:

```
.titledPane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.titledPane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.titledPane:focused > .title {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
.titledPane > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
.titledPane:focused > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
.titledPane:collapsed > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
.titledPane > .content {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

What other setting am I missing? I've a `GridPane` inside it, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Probably that's the dropshadow effect. Try `-fx-effect: null;` on the arrow. Btw: note that you can seperate the rules and use multiple selectors, e.g. `.titledPane, .titledPane > .title, .titledPane > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow { 
    -fx-background-insets: 0; }` `.titledPane > .content, .titledPane > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow, .titledPane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: white; }` `.titledPane:focused > .title {
    -fx-background-color: black; }`

Comment: @fabian Thank you so much!!! `-fx-effect: null;` solved it. If you put it in an answer, I can mark it as the solution, if you want.

Comment: Related question: [How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx).  Some answers there are quite old and based upon previous styling for JavaFX (Caspian vs Modena), so the solutions offered there may not be relevant to what you want to accomplish.